# WiFi turns on and off every few seconds since upgrading to 23.10

Tags: networking, 23.10, mac-mini

Since upgrading to 23.10 via the automated updater, my WiFi turns on and off every few seconds.
If you are fast you can click on it and confirm that all the settings are correct, so I assume if it would stay on, then the WiFi would connect. When I go to settings via the GUI, the option/icon for WiFi appears and disappears every few seconds.
I can connect to the internet using a tethered USB but the WiFi will not connect, simply because it keeps turning on an off every few seconds.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.